# Generating Function of distinct way of partitioned square sums of positive integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, sums-of-squares

Let's define a function $p_2(n)$ that it is total distinct way to write $n$ positive integer as sum  of square of positive integers. For example, $9$ can be partitioned as sum of squares in 4 distinct ways:

$$3^2$$
$$2^2 + 2^2+1^2$$
$$2^2 + 1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2$$
$$1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2$$

Thus
$p_2(9)=4$

I used the similar method of [partition function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) to find generating function for $p_2(n)$ and I have gotten

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{ \infty }p_2(n)q^n=(1+q^{1^2}+q^{2.1^2}+q^{3.1^2}+......)(1+q^{2^2}+q^{2.2^2}+q^{3.2^2}+......)(1+q^{3^2}+q^{2.3^2}+q^{3.3^2}+......)..$$

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{ \infty }p_2(n)q^n=\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{n^2})} $$

I expanded first terms of that product function

$$\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{n^2})=1-q-q^4+q^5-q^9+q^{10}+q^{13}-q^{14}-q^{16}+q^{17}+q^{20}-q^{21}+q^{34}-q^{35}-q^{36}+q^{37}-q^{38}+q^{39}+q^{40}-q^{42}-2q^{49}+q^{51}+q^{52}+........$$

I have not found any references for sum formula for  $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{n^2})$.

Is there any sum formula of $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{n^2})$  as we can express  $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{n})=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{ \infty }(-1)^n q^{\frac{n(3n-1)}{2}}$?

Thanks for references and links to related subject.

UPDATE: 9th December,2014

I have found a relation for that square sum partition function I would like to share it.

$$\Phi_2(q)=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{n^2})$$
$$\Phi_2(q)=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{(2n-1)^2})\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{(2n)^2})$$

$$\Phi_2(q)=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{(2n-1)^2})\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-(q^4)^{n^2})$$

$$\Phi_2(q)=\Phi_2(q^4)\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{(2n-1)^2}) \tag 1$$
$$\Phi_2(-q)=\Phi_2(q^4)\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1+q^{(2n-1)^2})$$

$$\Phi_2(-q)\Phi_2(q)=\Phi^2_2(q^4)\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1+q^{(2n-1)^2})\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{(2n-1)^2})$$

$$\Phi_2(-q)\Phi_2(q)=\Phi^2_2(q^4)\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-(q^2)^{(2n-1)^2}) \tag 2$$
If we use Equation 1 and put $q -->q^2$
$$\Phi_2(q^2)=\Phi_2(q^8)\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-(q^2)^{(2n-1)^2}) \tag 3$$

Now we can find and function relation for $\Phi_2(q)$ if we divide Equation 2 and  3

$$\frac{\Phi_2(-q)\Phi_2(q)}{\Phi_2(q^2)}=\frac{\Phi^2_2(q^4)}{\Phi_2(q^8)}$$

$$\Phi_2(-q)\Phi_2(q)\Phi_2(q^8)=\Phi^2_2(q^4)\Phi_2(q^2)  \tag 4$$

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{ \infty }p_2(n)q^n=\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{n^2})} =\frac{1}{\Phi_2(q)}$$

If we define $$P_2(q)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{ \infty }p_2(n)q^n$$

$$P_2(q)=\frac{1}{\Phi_2(q)}$$

If we put in Equation 4,

$$P_2(-q)P_2(q)P_2(q^8)=P^2_2(q^4)P_2(q^2)  \tag 5$$

Finally we can write square sum partition as function relation,

$$\left( \sum\limits_{n=0}^{ \infty }p_2(n)(-1)^nq^n \right) \left( \sum\limits_{n=0}^{ \infty }p_2(n)q^n \right) \left( \sum\limits_{n=0}^{ \infty }p_2(n)q^{8n}\right)=\left( \sum\limits_{n=0}^{ \infty }p_2(n)q^{4n} \right)^2 \left( \sum\limits_{n=0}^{ \infty }p_2(n)q^{2n} \right) $$

n terms can be sum both side and a relation can be found for square sum partition function but It is quite complex relationship. I could not get further. Can someone please help me or advice how to simplify it and get further from that point

Thanks a lot

Comment: I tried computing the first ten thousand coefficients, and didn't see a simple pattern. The coefficient on $q^n$ is occasionally greater than $n$: for instance, the coefficient on $q^{9911}$ is $19304$.

Comment: @zeb Thanks for comment. Do you mention you found $p_2(9911)=19304$ ? With direct sense of euler function sum formula, It may be cubic polynomial pattern but maybe there can be more  than one sum. It is just a sense . I have not found a pattern either.

Comment: Have you checked the OEIS references: https://oeis.org/A001156

Comment: @Mathlover I meant that the coefficient of $q^{9911}$ in $\prod_n (1-q^{n^2})$ is $19304$.

Comment: @zeb I did not expect that. I thought coefficients are (+1) or (-1) as euler function has. Is it possible if you share the coefficient result? Thanks

Comment: @Mathlover I just used pari to compute the coefficients. The command I used was something like "polcoeff(prod(k=1, sqrt(10000), 1-x^k^2+O(x^10001)), 9911)" and it ran in under a second. (I also didn't expect the coefficients to get so large, which is why I felt the need to comment on it.)

Comment: @Mathlover: already the coefficient of $x^{49}$ in that product is $-2$, so no new Euler-type result, sorry. Also, the coefficients of $x^i$ for $i=9500..9509$ are $-745$, $-1969$, $295$, $9240$, $-4856$, $-3624$, $2864$, $-5009$, $2438$, $5219$.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko : I updated the coefficient of  $x^{49}$. Euler is our master and I know the sum formula is not very easy and simple.  Maybe There is more than one sum.  It is also one reality that if it had a simple sum formula, I am sure that Euler had already found it many years ago. It is just my wonder how relationship has in it.Thanks a lot for comment and coefficients.

Comment: @Mathlover: you might also want to read about proofs of Euler's pentagonal theorem and other results of that sort (Gauss, Macdonald) that use Lie algebra cohomology. In these results it is important that exponents correspond to degrees of basis elements of certain infinite-dimensional Lie algebras. (Converting products like that into sums is computing Euler characteristics of the Chevalley-Eilenberg chain complex in two ways). However, the sequence of squares does not seem to correspond to a basis of any sensible (not too Abelian) Lie algebra; this is another reason to not expect good formulas